# RSA problem if I choose two specific small prime numbers?

Tags: rsa, algorithm-design

I know that RSA normally is made to make it with big integers, but i trying to make the algorithm myself (with the help of wikipedia) and I´m making it with small numbers to track the problems easily.

The problem is that sometimes the decryption of the encrypted message is wrong!
Exactly when I choose `p=11` and `q=5`, the rest goes like this:

```
n=55
euler(n)=40 = (p-1)(q-1)
e=13
d=37
```

the encrypted message (using message=65) is:

```
c=10
```

and using the chinese reminder theorem (wikipedia´s advise):

```
Dp=7
Dq=1
Qinv=9
m1=10
m2=0
h=2
```

and the decrypted message is:

```
message=10 !!!!!
```

It´s a problem of the chosen prime numbers?
I think that the rest I made it fine, I also check it with [rsa calculator](https://www.cs.drexel.edu/%7Ejpopyack/IntroCS/HW/RSAWorksheet.html).

I know also that to choose d and e there are more options, but the chosen ones they would be fine too. Maybe there is some other condition that is not on wikipedia?

Comment: Your only problem is that what you call message (65) is bigger than n (55). Your result (10) is the message reduced modulo n.

Answer (score 10):

Actually, that's an expected result since $65 \equiv 10 \pmod{55}$.

You should choose $m < n$ to avoid this problem.

Comment: One should also have $\: 0\leq m \;$. $\;\;\;\;$

Answer (score 6):

Apart from you're choosing a message greater than the modulus, another thing that might be confusing you is that, in this case, $C \equiv P \bmod N$.

That is, you take your message, 65, which is equivalent to 10 modulo 55, and encrypt it, and the result is 10, because $10^{13} \bmod 55 = 10$,  So, when you decrypt it, you take the ciphertext 10, and naturally get the plaintext back as 10, as $10^{37} \bmod 55 = 10$.

This "ciphertext is the same as the plaintext" is an artifact of using a tiny $N$; it does happen on real size RSA modulii, but with extremely low probability if the plaintext was chosen randomly.