# RSA incorrectly translates for small keys

Tags: rsa, prime-numbers, key-size

I've been learning about RSA and wrote my own implementation. I don't pretend to have intuitive understanding of RSA or that I understand *why* it works, but I believe to have some basic understanding of *how* it works, and believe that my implementation is valid. Due to time penalty of key generation, I set extremely low key size and had it encrypt and decrypt random numbers to check that it works. Here are randomly chosen parameters:

```
public: (326142389, 498429991)
private: (402424365, 498429991))
original message: 2256094460

final result: 262374496
```

Decrypting and encrypting failed to provide the original message. I wasn't sure what went wrong so I wanted to gather a couple more results. I had it print out a dozen more attempt results. Half of them successfully translated the message. This had me even more confused, so I ran some more tests. Here's the probability for translation failure (based on a sample of 100000). Left side shows the range from which the primes were generated, the right one the percentage of times translation failed (`decrypt(encrypt(message)) != message`)

```
      Primes range | Failure chance (%)
-------------------+-------------------
             10-99 | 100.00
           100-999 | 100.00
         1000-9999 |  99.36
       10000-99999 |  46.75
     100000-999999 |   0.00
   1000000-9999999 |   0.00
 10000000-99999999 |   0.00
```

While all these primes and keys are much *much* smaller than what I intend to use for real, I am wondering why this is happening. Is it a fault in my code which only reveals itself for tiny keys or is it inherent within the actual RSA algorithm?

Comment: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15021/rsa-problem-if-i-choose-two-specific-small-prime-numbers ?

Comment: @LightBit That's it... It completely slipped my mind that the message must be smaller than $n$